# Service-to-service in CloudRun

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have two services one is publicly available and another one is internal only.  Both services do not require `authentication`.   I connected both services via VPC connector but I am still not able to reach `internal` one.  Any thoughts what I could be missing?

[image]

Another part is confusing me is `Route all traffic through VPC`. If that service is the public how traffic will flow?

[image]

Thank you so much @guillaume blaquiere.  I am adding a bit juice to this question:

Here is visual diagram with details:
[image]

That is correct, it is working. I tested from compute.

> You are still able to reach the internal, it's not exception, all depends on from where you are testing! Add details if you want more help, but I can guaranty you the feature works!

I do not need egress. That is service purely only for specific logic in the app.

> The the serverless VPC connector is only about the egress traffic. So, the ingress (internal or public) behavior is not related to that part.

As u see it is only from `Service External` -> `Service Internal`

> Except if you want to reach the ingress internal service from your ingress All service. In that case you must set a egress connector (serverless VPC connector) and set the traffic to all.

Does it mean it would only works if both services would need to be enabled `Route all traffic through the VPC connecter`?  I am assume that will require to setup `egress` rule from that Serverless VPC connector.

> Indeed, even if the Cloud Run ingress is set to internal, the Cloud Run domain name is public. Therefore if you try to reach it, you will access to a public IP, and therefore you have to route the private AND the public traffic through your serverless VPC connector.

Answer (score 2):

If the traffic is set to internal, you can only access the service through your VPC, Load Balancer, shared VPC or VPC SC (as mentioned in the detail).

You are still able to reach the internal, it's not exception, all depends on from where you are testing! Add details if you want more help, but I can guaranty you the feature works!

The the serverless VPC connector is only about the egress traffic. So, the ingress (internal or public) behavior is not related to that part.

Except if you want to reach the ingress internal service from your ingress All service. In that case you must set a egress connector (serverless VPC connector) and set the traffic to all.

Indeed, even if the Cloud Run ingress is set to internal, the Cloud Run domain name is public. Therefore if you try to reach it, you will access to a public IP, and therefore you have to route the private AND the public traffic through your serverless VPC connector.

Keep in mind that the ingress internal is "only" an addition check perform on the traffic origin, it's not a "private" exposure as you have in your legacy environment.

Comment: Thanks @guillaume blaquiere! I added a bit more context in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Those who might be interested. I could not find the solution for my setup. So I had three choices: add auth validation check on endpoint, change pattern via `pubsub` or build LB in front of the public endpoint and switch to internal(`haven't tested though`). Since it was one off service that needed to be run at background I decided invoking via `pubsub`.

Also as far as summarizing issue:

1. [Available ingress settings](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress?_ga=2.258504008.-395878032.1671604384&_gac=1.19889226.1671604915.Cj0KCQiA14WdBhD8ARIsANao07hlVITDfKKOJne24kiMPZkAW8SPiq6gsUqsQoJ_3wCn3CTDpR9zBCsaAoA_EALw_wcB#settings)

[image]

2. [Accessing internal services](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress#internal-services)

Per documentation it seems it is possible get connected to another service via `VPC connector` but I was hitting the same issue. Assuming that we still keep another service as `allow unauthenticated`.  After switching traffic for `egress` to go via `VPC connector` my `front-end` could not reach endpoints, which seems something else needed for network.

[image]

Also when I was testing I was using `Custom domain` so that might be resolving public network or something.

[image]

It did not work for me but it might be will work for you. it would be interesting to hear.